# Express middleware not called when accessing socketio endpoint

Tags: express, socket.io

I have an application where I want to avoid robots to try to use my socket.io endpoint.

My socket.io sits on top of express:

```
const app = require('express')();
app.use(blockRobots);

const io = require('socket.io')(app{path: '/socket'});
```

If I access this server to any path except `/socket`, the middleware is executed.
However, doing a (GET) request to `/socket` does not trigger the middleware.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without delving into the code, I assume that `socket.io` attaches a listener to the HTTP server that gets triggered before Express gets to handle the request at all.

You can use the `allowRequest` option for `socket.io` to reject unwanted requests:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(app, {
  path: '/socket',
  allowRequest: (req, callback) => {
    if (CHECK_FOR_ROBOT) {
      return callback(null, false);
    } else {
      return callback(null, true);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer lead me to the right path.
The first check engine.io/Server does is checking for a `transport` query parameter. If that parameters does not exists it cancels the request flow. That's why in my case my middleware methods were not called.